# Which is the size between the title and the left side in Android Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to align several UI widgets to the title of each activity.

I will do that asing a margin left with the space between the back arrow and the left side of the screen. It is correct?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: That's a fairly large gap. Is there anything to the left of the those widgets?

Comment: No, the arrow only. I dont use custom action bar or any style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Designing App bar or list view [Google Official Documentation](https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) provides enough information for your requirement.Here is standard design Metrics according to google. 72dp for mobile and 80dp in Landscape Mode

[image: For Mobile]

[image: For Desktop]

Answer (score 2):

By Material Guide - 72 dp. Should work.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

72dp padding from the left side of the screen to the title.
Source: https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar